# Apply condition to opencv image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I would like to apply a boolean expression to an opencv image, evaluating the condition by pixel and creating a corresponding mask. To take a silly example, I'd like to evaluate B>100 & B<200 & G>40 in an image that is in BGR format.

I am able to apply a single condition (e.g. `img[:,:,0]>100`) but am not sure how to combine several of these with logical operators so that a boolean matrix results.

Also, is there a simpler way to specify this?

Comment: You can combine conditions using np.logical_and()

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `cv2.inrange()` function. You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html). You can pass lower and upper bound arrays and the function will check your values lie in between.

In your case, your bounding arrays can be something like, [100,40,0] and [200, 255, 255]

Comment: That would work for the example, but what I am need is a more general solution that allows for conditions that cannot be expressed as ranges.